# Google APIs in Javascript popup window( Error: Permission denied to access property "document")

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oauth

Here I am trying to fetch the user information like username , first name etc . By using google `authe2`, here is the following code

If I click

```
<a href='#' onclick='login();' id="login" '> Click here to login </a>  {onclick='login()'}
```

**login button**, I am getting access token but it's going to catch block and displaying an error like:

> Error: Permission denied to access property "document"

and pop up window is not closing. 
please help me how to solve this

```
  var OAUTHURL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?';
    var VALIDURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=';
    var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email';
    var CLIENTID = '{MY CLIENT ID}';
    var REDIRECT = '{My redirection URL}'
    var LOGOUT = 'http://accounts.google.com/Logout';
    var TYPE = 'token';
    var _url = OAUTHURL + 'scope=' + SCOPE + '&client_id=' + CLIENTID + '&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT + '&response_type=' + TYPE;
    var acToken;
    var tokenType;
    var expiresIn;
    var user;
    var loggedIn = false;

    function login() {
        var win = window.open(_url, "windowname", 'width=600, height=600');

        var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
            try {
                console.log(win.document.URL);
                if (win.document.URL.indexOf(REDIRECT) != -1) {
                    window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                    var url = win.document.URL;
                    acToken = gup(url, 'access_token');
                    tokenType = gup(url, 'token_type');
                    expiresIn = gup(url, 'expires_in');
                    win.close();

                    validateToken(acToken);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }, 500);
    }
```